# run same method in multiple task replce the previous object sent as a parameter

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

i  am running the task which have method called createpdf(obj);
i have a list of the same object and with the help of forEach loop i am creating a task of the createpdf method ;

but when the last task called the method it will change the all the previous object values also.

```
createpdf(obj){

}

createtask(){

Parallel.ForEach(objeclist, m => createpdf(m) );
}
```

now when the last task run it will change all the task result.

Comment: Could you provide code that sets objeclist variable ? It might be the list of references to the same object.

Comment: You sorely need to post a [mcve] for this question. Your code right now is very much incomplete.

Answer (score 0):

That is normal behavior for reference types when you change property of the same object by different links. Your list contains the different links to the same object and when one property is changed with createpdf method all reference notes to modified property as well.
Could read this article about difference reference and structure types in C#:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types

https://vegibit.com/reference-types-and-value-types-in-c/

If you want to separate instances for each objects in list  you should add to list new created instance of object or define them as structure instead class.